# Difficulty making Healpix compatible with GDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

PROBLEM:

I am having difficulty running Healpix-IDL routines with GDL with the current version of Healpix, Healpix_3.20.

The easiest thing to do would be to follow user `gilo` in this post:

http://sourceforge.net/p/gnudatalanguage/discussion/338692/thread/6546b9ad/?limit=25#324d

All Healpix IDL routines are downloaded in `~/user/downloads/Healpix_3.20/src/idl`

Then, use !PATH i.e.:

```
GDL> !PATH = expand_path('+/user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/')+':'+!PATH
```

and after that you have access to all healpix procedures within `gdl`

That doesn't work for me. I try the command `hidl` and `hididle` in the Terminal (I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite, 10.10.5):

```
GDL> hidl
% Procedure not found: HIDL
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

Any other solutions?

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
In the installation procedures install.pdf, Section 7.6 hidl usage describes that hidl is sometimes not recognized. A fix is setting the environment variable IDL STARTUP to be equal to the HEALPix startup file HEALPix startup including the directory path to the file, i.e. use

`setenv IDL_STARTUP /disk1/user1/HEALPix_2.15a/src/idl/HEALPix_startup` for C shell, csh

`export IDL_STARTUP="+/disk1/user1/HEALPix_2.15a/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"` for s, sh, bash

For my routines, this should be

```
export IDL_STARTUP="+/usr/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"
```

on bash Terminal
(Recall syntax:
`export key=value` is sh, ksh, bash
`setenv key value` is csh)
This doesn't work for me. After executing the command, and entering gdl, I get:

```
% Error opening startup file: /user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup
```

Following Section 7.8 Using GDL instead of IDL, I try

```
$ export IDL_TMPDIR=/tmp
$ gdl
```

This doesn't work either.
Following Using HEALPix IDL together with other IDL libraries in the IDL routines manual, idl.pdf, I try

```
export IDL_PATH="+/user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/:+/opt/local/share/gnudatalanguage/lib:<IDL_DEFAULT>"
export IDL_STARTUP="+/user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"gdl`
```

output error:

```
% Error opening startup file: /user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup.
```

I try

```
export IDL_PATH="+/opt/local/share/gnudatalanguage/lib:<IDL_DEFAULT>"
hidl
```

output error:

```
-bash: hidl: command not found
```

Nothing works.

BACKGROUND:

Healpix has the installation procedures here, at source forge.net: healpix.sourceforge.net/pdf/install.pdf

and the IDL routines here: healpix.sourceforge.net/pdf/idl.pdf

The sourcecode is here: sourceforge.net/projects/healpix/

In order to install Healpix, you use `./configure` and then `make`. (See install.pdf, section 4)

Healpix IDL routines are downloaded in `/user/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/`

GDL routines are located in `/opt/local/share/gnudatalanguage/lib/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subdirectory `~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin` there are two files, `config` and `idl.sh`.

The `config` is

```
# configuration for Healpix 3.20
HEALPIX=/Users/myname/downloads/Healpix_3.20 ; export HEALPIX
HPX_CONF_DIR=/Users/myname/.healpix/3_20_Darwin
if [ -r ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/idl.sh ] ; then . ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/idl.sh ; fi
if [ -r ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/f90.sh ] ; then . ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/f90.sh ; fi
if [ -r ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/cpp.sh ] ; then . ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/cpp.sh ; fi
if [ -r ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/c.sh ] ;   then . ${HPX_CONF_DIR}/c.sh ;   fi
```

The `idl.sh` file is

```
# IDL configuration for HEALPix Fri MONTH DAY TIME EDT YEAR
# make sure IDL related variables are global
export IDL_PATH IDL_STARTUP
# back up original IDL config, or give default value
OIDL_PATH="${IDL_PATH-<IDL_DEFAULT>}"
OIDL_STARTUP="${IDL_STARTUP}"
# create Healpix IDL config, and return to original config after running Healpix-enhanced IDL
HIDL_PATH="+${HEALPIX}/src/idl:${OIDL_PATH}"
HIDL_STARTUP="${HEALPIX}/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"
alias hidl="IDL_PATH=\"${HIDL_PATH}\"   ; IDL_STARTUP=${HIDL_STARTUP} ; idl   ; IDL_PATH=\"${OIDL_PATH}\" ; IDL_STARTUP=${OIDL_STARTUP} "
alias hidlde="IDL_PATH=\"${HIDL_PATH}\" ; IDL_STARTUP=${HIDL_STARTUP} ; idlde ; IDL_PATH=\"${OIDL_PATH}\" ; IDL_STARTUP=${OIDL_STARTUP} "
```

So, if I manually set the paths in this `idl.sh` file and run `config`, i.e `~/.config`. This should then allow one to use `hidl` in the command line to run the Healpix IDL routines, right?

Comment: For me, I just ran the `config` file and then I could run `hidl` from the command line. `hidl` just starts IDL with some paths set.

Comment: You mean, you first typed into the command line   `. ~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin/config` and then input `hidl`? 
It doesn't work for me. I get `-bash: idl: command not found`.

Comment: Or do you mean, you ran `./configure` as detailed in Section 4 here: http://healpix.sourceforge.net/pdf/install.pdf
Neither work.

Comment: I had previously ran `./configure`, that is what creates `~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin`. Then I run `. ~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin/config`, which should give you an `hidl` command. You are going to have to modify this `config` file if you want it to launch GDL instead of IDL.

Comment: @mgalloy The `config` file looks like it has no dependency on GDL. (By the way, I would use IDL, but poverty. I'm sorry.) I have edited the file `idl.sh` to be GDL compatible by editing all `IDL` to become `GDL`. Still, the `hidl` doesn't work. I'm not sure why....

Answer (score 1):

`hidl` is an alias to start IDL with the Healpix startup file and path. Type it on the system command line, not the IDL command line. You must run through their `configure` system to define `hidl`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Input `hidl` in the command line results in `-bash: hidl: command not found`. If I set the path using `!PATH=expand_path()` above inside GDL, quit, and then use `hidl`, it also doesn't work. Typing `export IDL_STARTUP="+/usr/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"` and then `hidl` in the Terminal also doesn't work. 

The Healpix configure system doesn't seem to affect `hidl`.

Comment: Did you run the `config` file the `configure` command creates in your home directory? You would do something like `. ~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin/config`.

Comment: In subdirectory `~/.healpix/3_20_Darwin` there are two files, `config` and `idl.sh`. See the answer below for more comments.

Comment: I found the error. My error was that for GDL_STARTUP, one cannot include the plus +, i.e. `export GDL_STARTUP="/Users/myname/downloads/Healpix_3.20/src/idl/HEALPix_startup"` but for GDL_PATH you should include the plus +, i.e. `export GDL_PATH="+/Users/myname/downloads/HEALPix_3.20/src/idl/:+/opt/local/share/gnudatalanguage/lib:<IDL_DEFAULT>"`